# Database password secure, encrypting with php does really makes difference?

Tags: security, passwords

About password and database secure, minding that the only way to user have acess to the user`s passwords is if he somehow acess the database itself (probably he got the db password), so does it really makes diference if the user password is hashed or encrypted?

  I`m asking cause if someone has acess to the database, he dont need the user password, he can make the changes on the database itself.
 About the encrypting, i find on php manual that blowfish is the most indicated, but ive found a online decrypter in the first result search in google, and plus, the hacker probably will know how to decrypt any password minding that he already get the db password itself.
What you think about that? Is password encryption really needed, and safe? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's what *hashing* is for

Comment: So what? people don't break into DBs to give themselves superuser privs so they can poke around your forum or whatever. They break into DBs to get credentials, because most people tend to reuse the same password on multiple sites. Your site may be "small", but it's pretty good odds that some of your users will use the same username/password on other sites, like their banks... The worst thing you can do is have a cavalier attitude towards security.

Comment: So just cause my site is small it wouldt need to be safe? I understand your answer, thanks for your time, but i`m asking cause, if the user has acess to the db itself, he can got the pass, hashed or encrypted than he can use brutal force to decrypt it (maybe he can use the same way he used to acess the pass to acess the salt, even if its a salt per user). It may take time, but can be made, wont it?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody could use SQL injection to get the password of a user. In this case, he might not be able to access any table besides the user table, so

> does it really makes diference if the user password is hashed or encrypted

yes. And besides that point, if you have moderators, developers, and you looking at this table, I, as a user, would feel more comfortable if you were looking at a hash, and not the actual password because I may use that password on other sites. Overall it provides more security and comfort for your users, so the real question is, why not?

Comment: But thinking in that way, would pointing us to not just encrypt the password, but a lot of user variables that he would`t like us to see, perhaps, anyone who really want, and work with the db`s can see them (by decrypting). And about sql injection, this just make`s the password harder to detect using brutal force, but anyway, it can be done, wont it?

Comment: @sagits You're right, there is a certain level of trust that your users bestow, but passwords are typically more delicate than information like name, address, and email. You need to protect your ignorant users who might use the same password for their bank account, email, and facebook. SQL injection is different than cracking a password. You should read up on it because it's very important for security.

Answer (score 0):

> About the encrypting, i find on php manual that blowfish is the most
>   indicated, but ive found a online decrypter in the first result search
>   in google

The best solution is to hash your passwords, not encrypt them. Many people make the mistake of confusing encryption with hashing (and vice versa). Encrypted text can be decrypted, whereas hashing is a one-way street. i.e. Once you hash something, you can't "de-hash" it. What you're looking for is [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), which is a hashing algorithm that is ***based on*** the [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) cipher.

In regards to an attacker gaining access to your password hashes:

> Besides incorporating a salt to protect against rainbow table attacks,
>   bcrypt is an adaptive function: over time, the iteration count can be
>   increased to **make it slower**, so it remains resistant to brute-force
>   search attacks even with increasing computation power.

The great thing about Bcrypt is that it is slow, which means that it is relatively expensive to try and crack a Bcrypt hash (depending on iterations and randomness of salt).

Answer (score 0):

If an attacker gets hold of a user’s password, he has his password.
If an attacker gets hold of a hash of a user’s password, he has only a hash of the password and not the password itself.

Now think of the laziness of people: chances are that the retrieved passwords are not unique to this account but do also work for other accounts (e-mail, Twitter, Facebook, etc.). This actually happens all the time.

If you just store a hash of the user’s password using a strong password hashing scheme like bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2, the hacker would need a lot of resources (time or processing power) to guess or brute-force passwords.

By the way: hash functions are not invertible. Those hash reversing sites are just huge lookup tables that return *one* password for an already known password+hash pair.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do some additions to the already given good answers.

First, the Blowfish you mentioned is indeed an encryption algorithm and can be decrypted. But don't mix up **Blowfish** with **BCrypt** which is a hashing algorithm based on Blowfish.

Second, you hash the passwords for an attacker that can **read** your database. Getting read access is much easier than write access, an often used technique is SQL-injection. You can try it out yourself in this [demo](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/hash_sqlinjection.php), click on the → arrow to fill in a prepared input.

1. So while an attacker can maybe read your database, this doesn't mean he can write to it. Because he knows only the hash of the password, he cannot enter the original password in the login form.
2. If the attacker has write access too, you cannot prevent him from using your account, but he still doesn't know the original password and cannot try it on other websites.